# Funcion codeigniter funciona en windows pero no en linux

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Desarrolle esta funcion para subir archivos al servidor pero no entiendo por que funciona en windows y no en linux centOS 7, para que funcione en linux se debe configurar algo ? permisos o algo ? ya cambie permisos de las carpetas y tambien revise la ruta al parecer todo esta bien, el tamano del archivo tambien probe con varios tamanos y quite la configuracion del tamano pero no funciona. Por favor necesito resolverlo ya que en el trabajo uso linux y en casa windows

```
public function addProduct(){
            $archivo = $this->filePath();
            $result = $this->m->addProduct($archivo);
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'add';
    if($result){
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}

    public function filePath(){

        $config['upload_path'] = realpath('../image/product/') ;
        $config['allowed_types'] = "*";//"gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG";
        $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = "50000";
        $config['max_width'] = "2000";
        $config['max_height'] = "2000";

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $res =  '';

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('txtFoto') ) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $res = 'hola no funciona'; 

        }else { 

            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path = './image/product/'.$file_data['file_name'];
            $res = $file_path;

        } 
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: activa los logs en codeigniter, que te aparece cuando lo corres en linux ?

Comment: Guarda normal el texto y todo pero lo que no guarda es la imagen ni el path

Comment: tienes que crear el path primero y revisar los permisos

Comment: ya estan creadas las carpetas les di permisos de lectura y escritura para mi usuario pero no gurda nada solo texto y tampoco la imagen

Comment: publica un zip con el proyecto y te ayudo a solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tienes activado el .htaccess para no usar el index.php

vista

```
<form action="<?= base_url('generals/upload_files/addProduct')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" type="image" name="type">
    <input type="text" name="product_name">
    <input type="text" name="product_price">
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

application/controllers/generals/upload_files.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload_files extends CI_Controller {
    public $images            = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
    public $pdfs              = 'pdf';

    public function addProduct(){
        $type_file            = $this->input->post('type', TRUE);
        $info_product         = array(
                                      'name' => $this->input->post('product_name', TRUE),
                                      'price'=> $this->input->post('product_price', TRUE)
                                     );

        switch($type_file){
            case 'image':
                $info_file    = $this->_uploadFile($this->images);
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $info_file    = $this->_uploadFile($this->pdfs);
                break;
        }

        $msg['success']       = false;

        $prod_id              = $this->model_insert_product->addInfoProduct($info_product);
        if( $info_file !== 'error'){
            $result           = $this->model_insert_product->addProduct($info_file, $prod_id);
            $msg['success']   = true;
        }

        $msg['type']          = 'add';

        echo json_encode($msg);
    }

    protected function _uploadFile($types){

        $config['upload_path']   = './image/product/');
        $config['allowed_types'] = $types;
        $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;
        $config['max_size']      = "50000";
        if( strpos($types, 'jpg')){
            $config['max_width'] = 0;
            $config['max_height']= 0;
        }

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
            log_message('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
            $res                 = 'error'; 
        }
        else{ 
            $file_data           = $this->upload->data();
            $res                 = $file_data->full_path;
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

application/models/model_insert_product.php

```
function addInfoProduct($info_product){
    $this->db->insert('table1', $info_product);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

function addProduct($info_file, $prod_id){
    $this->db->insert('table2', array('fk_table1' => $product_id, 'img_path' => $info_file));

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: Pues si entiendo eso el problema es linux, al parecer por cuestion de permisos o algo asi o tal vez mayúsculas minúsculas ya que linux es estricto en eso y hasta ahora no logro resolverlo aunque por el momento funciona pero en windows.

Comment: en linux que error te sale?

Comment: nada de errores pero no guarda solo guarda los datos de los inputs... pero no el path ni la imagen a la carpeta que asigne

Comment: en linux si le asignas permisos a la carpeta donde se guarda la imagen?

Comment: si tienen permisos de lectura y escritura... pero me parece muy raro que no guarde o kisa hay que configurar rutas tambien para poder hacerlo eso, pero seguire haciendo pruebas hasta q funcione

Comment: Hace tiempo tuve un problema similar (pero no con codeigniter) al cambiar mi entorno de desarrollo de windows a linux. Los archivos de código php, css, js, etc. son texto plano (pero no tan plano en windows) **windows los guarda con BOM** y _linux sin BOM_, Al leerlos para ejecución si no se ha eliminado la marca (BOM) pasa de todo. Es posible que el comportamiento anotado tenga que ver con eso.

Comment: Olvidé indicar cuando se usa formato UTF-8 que suele ser el default